# How to allow only 1 connection to BlueZ GATT server at any given moment?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I'm working on Bluetooth on the embedded Linux. I'm using BlueZ and D-Bus. I have a server taken from the example https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server.
I have the app such as nRF installed in 2 iPhones. I'm able to connect to my Linux Bluetooth server at the same time. I'm able to modify the characteristic from either of the iPhone app. But this is a problem because we don't want it. We'd like to have only 1 phone connected to the Linux device. That way, the same characteristic won't be modified by more than 1 phone app at the same time.
Is there a way to allow only 1 connection to the Linux Bluetooth GATT server at any given time? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way to do this is to disable/stop advertisements on your Linux device as soon as a connection is established. This way, upon a connection, your Linux device will no longer be advertising and remote devices will no longer be able to connect to it.